# How to pass real-time audio stream to the Direct Line Speech endpoint?

Tags: c#, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am trying to use Direct Line Speech (DLS) in my custom voice app. The Voice app has access to the real-time audio streams which I want to (pcm encoded) it directly to Direct Line Speech that allows a back and forth communication in real-time.

From the DLS Client sample code (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Services-Direct-Line-Speech-Client), I see that the method ListenOneAsync() in Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Dialog.DialogServiceConnector namespace, but looks like it's capturing media from local microphone.

But looking at the reply here ([Is new ms botbuilder directline speech good fit for call center scenario?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56340032/is-new-ms-botbuilder-directline-speech-good-fit-for-call-center-scenario)), it seems I can send the audio stream to the DLS directly. I can't seem to find any documentation around this. Can someone shed some light on how to achieve this?

Comment: Are you hoping to send audio from a pre-recorded file?

Comment: No, I am trying to connect it to a streaming real time endpoint

Comment: @KyleDelaney - I just came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53209752/speech-recognition-with-microsoft-cognitive-speech-api-and-non-microphone-real-t) which is similar to my problem except that I have a real time endpoint and I need continuous back and forth with the Direct Line Speech client.

Comment: So to be clear, you have a web app that has web sockets for both incoming and outgoing audio streams and you're using it to forward audio from some other source to Direct Line Speech?

Comment: yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your answer lies in the [`Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Audio.AudioConfig`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.audio.audioconfig) class. Have a look at [this line](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Services-Direct-Line-Speech-Client/blob/master/DLSpeechClient/MainWindow.xaml.cs#L268) in the Direct Line Speech client:

> ```
> this.connector = new DialogServiceConnector(config, AudioConfig.FromDefaultMicrophoneInput());
> ```

`AudioConfig` provides many options besides `FromDefaultMicrophoneInput`. I suspect you'll want to use one of the three [`FromStreamInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.audio.audioconfig.fromstreaminput) overloads. If you do that then `ListenOnceAsync` will use your stream instead of the microphone.

Comment: Thanks Kyle! I'm trying this out.

Comment: @bedtym - Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if it helps you

Comment: Thanks Kyle, I think this does give me some result, but I can't seem to understand how to hook up Direct Line speech with with continuous 'streaming' real-time media.

Comment: I've posted a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58295798/how-to-hook-real-time-audio-stream-endpoint-to-direct-line-speech-endpoint) which is continuation of this question - hope you can help me out.